# Сборка Webpack (стили)

Tags: css, webpack, build, styled-components

Помогите, пожалуйста, найти где ошибка: собираю в Webpack проект, и хочу при билде компилировать js стили (styled components) в css. Проект собирается, но стили всё равно остаются в js формате.
Сам проект: https://github.com/margo-ai/book-searching